# Linq-C# Query For Dynamic Search Page

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

The following is my original code which queries SQL Server using an Entity Framework context. It queries the database and uses the StartsWith method to match the string entered by the user client side. This allows for the user to enter any combination of the three fields (FirstName, LastName, and HOHUPI).

```
 var results = db.APPLICANTs.Where(p => (p.RESP_FRST.StartsWith(model.FirstName) || model.FirstName == null)
                && (p.RESP_LST.StartsWith(model.LastName) || model.LastName == null) && (p.HOH_UPI.ToString().StartsWith(model.HOHUPI) || model.HOHUPI == null))
                .OrderBy(p => p.RESP_FRST);
```

This query looks in only 1 table (Applicant). However, I have another table (Contact_Info) which I need to include in the results. I do not have a navigation property in the EF model.

I've tried the following:

```
 var hID = from APPLICANT in context.APPLICANTs
                          join CONTACT_INFO in context.CONTACT_INFO on APPLICANT.HOH_UPI equals CONTACT_INFO.HOH_UPI
                          where (APPLICANT.HOH_UPI.ToString().StartsWith(model.HOHUPI)) && (APPLICANT.RESP_FRST.StartsWith(model.FirstName))
                          && (APPLICANT.RESP_LST.StartsWith(model.LastName)) && (CONTACT_INFO.HM_PHN_NMB.ToString().StartsWith(model.HM_PHN_NMB))
                          orderby APPLICANT.RESP_FRST
                          select APPLICANT;

               model.SearchResults = hID.ToPagedList(pageIndex, RecordsPerPage);
```

This works but only if the user enters values in all 4 text boxes (first name, last name, hohupi, and phone number. I need help in formulating the query so that the user can search by only 1 or any combination of text boxes.

The primary key in the applicant table is HOH_UPI and the foreign key in the Contact_Info table is HOH_UPI.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working:

```
 var hID = from APPLICANT in context.APPLICANTs
                          join CONTACT_INFO in context.CONTACT_INFO on APPLICANT.HOH_UPI equals CONTACT_INFO.HOH_UPI
                          where (APPLICANT.HOH_UPI.ToString().StartsWith(model.HOHUPI) || model.HOHUPI == null) && (APPLICANT.RESP_FRST.StartsWith(model.FirstName) || model.FirstName == null)
                          && (APPLICANT.RESP_LST.StartsWith(model.LastName) || model.LastName == null) && (CONTACT_INFO.HM_PHN_NMB.ToString().StartsWith(model.HM_PHN_NMB) || model.HM_PHN_NMB == null)
                          orderby APPLICANT.RESP_FRST
                          select APPLICANT;
```

Knowing where to use the logical AND (&&) and OR (||) was the key.